# Where do I need to set the $PATH variable so that .desktop file can see when i am using zsh as my default shell

Tags: debian, zsh, gnome3, .desktop

I am using Debian 12. Gnome 43. zsh is my default shell (`sudo chsh --shell /usr/bin/zsh ismail`).

In my .zshrc, I have set the path variable like:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

The alacritty binary is located in:

```
% which alacritty
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin/alacritty
```

The following desktop file works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec="/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin/alacritty"
Icon=Alacritty
Terminal=false
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;
```

The following desktop file does not work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=alacritty
Icon=Alacritty
Terminal=false
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;
```

I have no idea why this is not working.

I want to point out one thing.

```
$ which foliate
/usr/bin/foliate
```

If I set `Exec=foliate`, then it works. So, I guess it has something to do with the path. The system that runs `.desktop` files is not probably seeing the path variable set in `.zshrc`.

What can I do at this point.

**Update 1:**

If I use the following desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "zsh -c 'echo $PATH;$SHELL'"
Icon=Alacritty
Terminal=false
Categories=System;TerminalEmulator;

Name=Alacritty
GenericName=Terminal
Comment=A fast, cross-platform, OpenGL terminal emulator
StartupWMClass=Alacritty
Actions=New;
```

Then the path variables are:

```
/home/ismail/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin

% echo $SHELL        
/usr/bin/zsh

% echo $PATH 
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin:/home/ismail/.local/bin:/home/ismail/bin:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/git-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/python-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/bash-scripts:/home/ismail/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

So the desktop file is not seeing the first part or the path variable which i set later in .zshrc (`/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin:/home/ismail/.local/bin:/home/ismail/bin:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/git-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/python-scripts:/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/bash-scripts:`).

Where do I need to set the $PATH variable so that `.desktop` file can see when i am using zsh as my default shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

When bash is the default shell, have to use `.profile` to set environment variables.

When zsh is the default shell, have to use `.zshenv` to set environment variables.

we must logout then login to get the path variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your desktop environment does not care about your shell settings.

You have to mirror this setting in the way your DE expects (which differs from DE to DE).

Comment: I am looking at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys for `TryExec` it says "If the path is not an absolute path, the file is looked up in the $PATH environment variable."

Comment: @AhmadIsmail Sure. But how is that related to my statement? Which DE do you use?

Comment: I am using gnome 43.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: You are right, "If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the desktop environment." However, I have tried .zshenv, .zshrc, .profile,. .gnomerc , nothing is working.